# How to convert Mono<Flux<T>> to Flux<T>

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, flux

I use spring webflux. I want to save some objects into database with R2dbc mysql, this save function return Flux , so I got a Mono<Flux> finally but I want to a Flux

```
public Mono<Flux<Brand>> refreshBrands() {
        return Flux.fromIterable(commonService.parseProduct())// retrieve products
                .flatMap(this::fetchBrandsWithWebClient)// map product to it's brands
                .filter(Brand::isNotEmptyBrand) // filter invalid ones
                .distinct()
                .collectList() // get all with list
                .map(brandRepo::saveAll); // save brands into database
```

At the beginning I retrieved some defined products and transfer them to brands with a crawler based on spring webclient , then I save them all with saveAll function with R2dbc operation. I actually need a Flux publisher but right now this function return a Mono<Flux>. How to implement this? Thanks.

Comment: show brandRepo.saveAll method signature

Comment: <S extends T> Flux<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities);@kerbermeister

Comment: I resolved it

`return Mono.fromCallable(commonService::parseProduct)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
                .flatMap(this::fetchBrandsWithWebClient)
                .filter(Brand::isNotEmptyBrand)
                .distinct()
                .collectList()
                .flatMapMany(brandRepo::saveAll);`